# Linux shell script to count files and delete when they exceed a number

Tags: linux, shell

I want to run a cron job that delete all files in a directory when it exceeds a number.

For example when it become 1000 files, then delete all files in that directory.

The goal is clearing cache directory.

Comment: Note this is *extremely* likely to horribly confuse any program that is currently running and accessing that cache... What kind of cache is it? `firefox`? `squid`?

Comment: Make the program correctly handle caching. The problem with what you want is that you're making the cache to malfunction.

Comment: why? website have thousands pages that maybe cached at first call.

Comment: @exim I think what hdante is getting at is that the caching code in the php script should not only create new entries, but also monitor how large the cache is getting and do its own culling of old entries. That shouldn't have to be handled by an external brute-force process.

Comment: I agree with handling it properly in the php script. But, why delete all files when it reaches 1000? Typically just delete those entries over the threshold - namely the least recently used entries aka LRU cache.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
CACHE_DIR=/home/cache
if [[ `ls -al $CACHE_DIR | wc -l` -ge 1000 ]] ; then 
     find $CACHE_DIR -t file -exec rm -f {} \; 
fi;
```

delete all regular files in /home/cache more if the count of files equals and greater than 1000.

Comment: why the R option to rm if it's a regular file? and you can change the end with `-exec rm -f '{}' +`  (`+`, on "recent" find, will put as many arguments there as it can, speeding things up as you have much less invocations of the rm command)

Comment: @exim It had to be considered as a pseudo script. But, you're right. just updated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting all files, a typical Least Recently Used (LRU) cache just deletes those older entries not recently used and keeps the recently used entries.

```
ls -ut1 | tail -n+1001 | xargs -n 50 rm
```

That will sort all files in the dir by access time, least recently accessed to bottom. Tail omits the top 1000 and sends the rest to 'xargs rm' which deletes em. The '-n 50' option for xargs could be needed if the file names are long and cause a single command length to exceed the ARG_MAX.

In case there are less than 1000 files then 'xargs rm' complains. To clear that up;

```
ls -ut1 | tail -n+1001 > /tmp/files$$
if [[ `cat /tmp/files$$ | wc -l` -ge 1001 ]] ; then
  while read line ; do
    rm "$line"
  done < /tmp/files$$
fi
rm /tmp/file$$
```

Comment: `touch "will not work"; ls -ut1 | head -n 1 | xargs -n 50 cat`

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Ah, xargs doesn't work if file names have spaces - in which case my 2nd solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Again, `xargs` to the rescue!

```
(echo ; ls -1 ) | head -n -1000 | head -n 1 | xargs -r rm -f *
```

First part creates a list of all files in the directory, but with a blank line in front

second, keep all but the last 1000 lines. If less than 1000 files, keeps nothing!

third, keep only first line - which is either the empty line or nothing (if less than 1000 files)

last, run the command `rm -f *` ONLY if there was at least a single line of input (that's the `-r` option)

EDIT:

Ok, apparently the `*` doesn't work in scripts. So using the idea from fedorqui, you can use this:

```
(echo ; ls -1 ) | head -n -1000 | head -n 1 | xargs -r ls -1 | xargs rm -f
```

So instead of doing `rm -f *`, you do `ls -1` only if there are more than 1000 files (and taking the output into `rm`)